# pmount cant mount ntfs USB, while mount can

Tags: mount, ubuntu-22.04, ntfs-3g

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.1

```
$ pmount /dev/sda1

NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sda1' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

but `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /media/` works

How can I fix pmount or mount without root?

Comment: I failed to solve it and switched from pmount to [udisks2](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/udisks)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to do `sudo ntfsfix dev/desired drive here`

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**